# How to join two tables in flask-sqlalchemy and return data of both parent and child tables in single query?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to join two tables and get the data in single query, but i only get id from child table.
below are models setup:

what is the best way to achieve this:

build parent child relationship and get whole data including child table through calling parent table.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```py
class img_details(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(4000), unique=False)
    short_description = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    address = db.relationship('address', backref='img_details')

    def __init__(self,
                 img_url,
                 description,
                 short_description,

                 ):
        self.img_url = img_url
        self.description = description
        self.short_description = short_description



class address(db.Model):
    idaddress = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    zip_code = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    img_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('img_details.id'))

    def __init__(self,
                 city,
                 state,
                 zip_code,
                 img_id
                 ):
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip_code = zip_code
        self.img_id = img_id


@bp.route('/user_data', methods=["GET"])
def get_user_data():
    all_list = img_details.query.join(address).all()
    result = user_data.dump(all_list)
    return jsonify({'submitted_records': result})

type here
```

```json
output result:
{
    "submitted_records": [
        {
            "address": [
                {
                    "city": "tet",
                    "idaddress": 123
                }
            ],
            "description": "Application Development full Stack",
            "id": 50,
            "img_url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000//uploads/profilepic1.jpg",
            "short_description": "Software Application engineer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a list of tuples in the result variable?
could you please show us its output format?

Comment: Hi, I added output in question, please review it.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: removed code and added json output

Comment: @AliMassoud
```json
{
    "submitted_records": [
        {
            "address": [
                123
            ],
            "description": "Application Development full Stack",
            "id": 50,
            "img_url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000//uploads/profilepic1.jpg",
            "short_description": "Software Application engineer"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @venkatg
Can you query only address table for a specific ID (let's take 123) that exists in img_details and get us the output?
it seems to work since it is getting you the addressid and the city with it, but there is something wrong since it is not getting you the zip_code and state.
also things to test:
- could you use (instead of .all()) .add_columns(here specify the columns you want to get like address.state)
and check what you get and update us.

Comment: @AliMassoud Hi, query address table worked.

```json

{
    "submitted_records": [
        {
            "city": "tet",
            "idaddress": 123,
            "img_details": {
                "description": "Application Development full Stack",
                "id": 50,
                "img_url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000//uploads/profilepic1.jpg",
                "short_description": "Software Application engineer"
            },
            "state": "test",
            "zip_code": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @venkatg Can you test this address = db.relationship('address', backref='img_details', lazy='joined')?

Comment: @AliMassoud Nope no result, this time i dont get anything.